# Exporting image data from an HTML canvas results in "Tainted Canvas" error or white image

Tags: javascript

The following code crops a portion of an image. I'd like to get the image data for the cropped area in base64, and I tried to do it using `context.toDataURL()`:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();
//imageObj.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

imageObj.onload = function () {

  // crop from 0,0, to 250,150
  var cropX = 0;
  var cropY = 0;
  var cropWidth = 250;
  var cropHeight = 150;

  //resize our canvas to match the size of the cropped area
  canvas.style.width = cropWidth;
  canvas.style.height = cropHeight;

  //fill canvas with cropped image
  context.drawImage(
    imageObj,
    cropX, cropY,
    cropWidth, cropHeight,
    0, 0,
    canvas.width, canvas.height
  );
}

imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
setTimeout(() => {
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  console.log(dataURL);
  $("#my_image").attr("scr", dataURL);
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <img id="my_image" src="" style="border:1px solid red;">
  </body>
</html>
```

However, it either shows a blank image or I get this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use your own images.

Comment: A "tainted canvas" contains image data from a domain that is not your domain. You cannot access the image information (the pixels).

Comment: Search for CORS - you are not allowed to programmatically access the image, due to security concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to save an image that's been fetched from an external source. [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) does not allow this unless the site the image has been fetched from explicitly has you whitelisted:

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and the Fetch API follow the same-origin policy. This means that a web application using those APIs can only request resources from the same origin the application was loaded from unless the response from other origins includes the right CORS headers.

If you need to save image information, use an image that you have local access to (e.g. from your `assets` folder or a file upload).

Comment: in other words, if I directly load my image from my `assets` folder, I won't have this problem ..?

Comment: Yes. Local images are same-origin, and so are not subject to the security restrictions that CORS imposes.

Comment: @yavg Notice, that you can use a cross-domain image, if it's __served__ with cross-origin allowing headers, and the image element has `crossOrigin` property set. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image